# Asymptotics for certain sum involving the divisor function, Ramanujan sum

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics

Let $c_q(n)$ be the Ramanujan sum, and let $\tau(n)$ be the divisor function. Is there an asymptotic formula for $$\sum_{n\le x}\tau(n)c_q(n)$$ with error terms that do not depend on $q$?

Comment: Substituting $c_q(n)=\sum_{d\mid (q,n)}d\mu(q/d)$ one can reduce this problem to the divisor problem in arithmetic progressions. This problem is well-studied, see Sándor, Jó.; Mitrinović, D. S. & Crstici, B. Handbook of number theory. I, § II.16 The divisor problem in arithmetic progressions.

Comment: Do you know of any other references for that problem?

Comment: This "handbook" contains different references. What is wrong with them?

Comment: I don't have access to it.

Comment: http://gen.lib.rus.ec/ http://booksee.org/